# Can't pull docker image in a specific VM

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I have a Docker image in my private registry. I can pull it from a VM or locally just fine, but in another VM it's stuck failing and retrying to pull certain layers.

I have tried:

- Pushing the image to another registry and pulling, same thing happens.
- `docker container prune`
- `docker image prune -a`

This is the pull log

```
4007a89234b4: Retrying in 18 seconds 
a7ad02e8d19d: Waiting 
ee1966ba2192: Waiting 
b0defeaff459: Waiting 
cece60e82a32: Waiting 
c44dd486dcc0: Waiting 
83d14123388c: Waiting 
6875956b229b: Waiting 
349f1875fd67: Pulling fs layer 
5d59d9ecc829: Waiting 
887108681808: Pulling fs layer 
2d364e941d12: Waiting 
9ec3da86a572: Pulling fs layer 
190a6364d67f: Waiting 
94d59721b79f: Waiting 
493b2438cf44: Waiting 
b008307a92d3: Waiting 
bf892b1ef981: Waiting 
585e4ff13e80: Waiting 
a03914f26841: Waiting 
4c0929e88c00: Pulling fs layer 
f4da096f7004: Waiting
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `curl -v https://<registry_base_url>/v2/_catalog` is useful to test connectivity from a vm to your private registry.

Comment: @ChrisBecke Connectivity is fine

Comment: well if basic connectivity is fine, the next step would be to check dockers specific configuration: `docker info` should reveal any proxies that docker has discovered and is trying to use.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue, found that it is because the disk was full on docker proxy server. After clearing some disk I am able to pull the image.